# Blocking all traffic except from ELB security groups, nginx responds with 502

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

I hope you can help me.
I have succesfully configured an ELB attached to two ec2 instances.
ELB listens on port 443 and forwards to port 80.

Everything works as expected.

What I want to achieve now is to block all traffic to the ec2 instances except the one coming from the ELB.

I have a created a new security group:

```
Accept all from sg-xxxxx
```

Where sg-xxx is the security group of the ELB which is set to:

```
Accept HTTPS from 0.0.0.0/0 | 0:*
```

I go the ec2 instance, remove the default SG and assign the newly created SG to accept traffic only from the ELB (networking, assign security group) server responds with:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx/1.15.8</center>
</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What `0.0.0.0/10` is supposed to mean? Maybe you wanted `0.0.0.0/0` for your ELB?

Comment: @Marcin, typo, edited, thanks

Comment: Your instances are reachable as it is `nginx/1.15.8` responding, not ELB with the error. Thus i would look at nginx? Maybe your app stopped running?

Comment: Yes, but why it responds with 502 only if I use that security group? default security group works, it's really weird

Comment: I don't know. nginx should produce some logs. Maybe they provide some useful info?

Comment: tailing the logs as soon as I switch SG I get:

1132: *83 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream

Comment: Restarting php-fpm or ngix didn't help..

Comment: If you login to the instance, and curl it from the inside, does it work as expected?

Comment: What are the Outbound rules set in the new security group?

Comment: @Geeshan all traffic -  All 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious, what if it's not the presence of the new security group, but the absence of the old one, that's causing the problem?  Something else -- such as an external database or server -- is trusting this EC2 instance based on its membership in the old SG that you are removing.  Disconnecting it breaks the application, resulting in the error.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended configuration would be:

- A security group on the Load Balancer (`LB-SG`) with:

  - Inbound rules: ports 80 and 443 from `0.0.0.0/0`
  - Outbound rules: Allow all traffic
- A security group on each Amazon EC2 instance (`App-SG`) with:

  - Inbound rules: port 80 from `LB-SG`
  - Outbound rules: Allow all traffic

That is, the `App-SG` should accept inbound traffic from `LB-SG` by referencing the other security group.

It is recommended to always allow all outbound traffic, since applications running on your own instance should be "trusted" unless you specifically want to lock-down security.